# How to reshape (pivot_wider and pivot_longer) a pandas DataFame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

I'm struggling in reshaping DataFrame (a little complicated) using pandas.

I have tried using `pd.melt`, `.pivot(index=, columns=, values=)`, but it doesn't work perfectly as I intended.

as is :

| date | location | char1 | char2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-01 | A | a | x |
| 22-01 | B | b | y |
| 22-01 | C | c | z |

to be :

| date | char | location.A | location.B | location.C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-01 | char1 | a | b | c |
| 22-01 | char2 | x | y | z |

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) before [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt(['date','location'], var_name='char')
        .pivot(index=['date','char'], columns='location', values='value')
        .add_prefix('location.')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
    date   char location.A location.B location.C
0  22-01  char1          a          b          c
1  22-01  char2          x          y          z
```

Or [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['date','location'])
         .rename_axis('char', axis=1)
         .stack()
         .unstack(level=1)
         .add_prefix('location.')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       )
print (df1)
    date   char location.A location.B location.C
0  22-01  char1          a          b          c
1  22-01  char2          x          y          z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) with [`pivot_wider`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider) and [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

(df.pivot_wider(index='date', names_from='location',
                names_glue = "{_value}_location.{location}")
   .pivot_longer(index='date', names_to=('char', '.value'), names_sep='_')
)
```

Output:

```
    date   char location.A location.B location.C
0  22-01  char1          a          b          c
1  22-01  char2          x          y          z
```

With pure pandas, you can use a [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) (`T`) in between [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
out = (df.set_index(['location', 'date']).T.rename_axis('char').stack()
         .add_prefix('location.').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
    char   date location.A location.B location.C
0  char1  22-01          a          b          c
1  char2  22-01          x          y          z
```